# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que en un "div" dentro del documento me haga la acción onClick general?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, reactjs, typescript

Mi caso es el siguiente:

Usando React, tengo un componente que pinta por pantalla un div cualquiera. En el evento "click" del documento tengo que me muestre un alert. Quiero evitar que cuando haga click en ese div me evite esa función, y me haga su propia función.

Esto viene a ser lo siguiente:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Hijo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="tabla"/>
        );
    }
}

----------------------------------------------

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Hijo from './Hijo'

export default class Padre extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            //Quiero algo asi
            if(document.getElementsByClassName("tabla")[0].click()){
                miFuncion()   
            }
            else{
                alert("Click fuera de la tabla")
            }
        })                  
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Hijo />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Alguna solución?

Comment: ¿Ninguna de las respuestas ha sido la correcta?

Answer (score 1):

Te daré la solución en React.

Primero, los eventos en React no son eventos nativos, son clases propias de React que exponen un API similar a los eventos nativos esta clase es [SyntheticEvent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html), cuando llamas a la función stopPropagation de un SyntheticEvent no estas deteniendo la propagación del evento nativo sino del evento React, esto te causa conflicto ya que tu agregas un handler nativo al document por lo tanto llamar a la función stopPropagation de SyntheticEvent no tiene ningún efecto, la solución es parar la propagación en el evento nativo para ello debes acceder al evento nativo a través de la propiedad nativeEvent de SyntheticEvent.

Fíjate en la siguiente implementación

```
class Hijo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="tabla" style={{height: '200px', backgroundColor: 'red', width: '200px'}} onClick={this._onClickHandler}></div>
        );
    }

    _onClickHandler = (e) => {
        console.log('Click en la tabla, detiene la propagacion del evento al padre y al document');
        e.stopPropagation(); // detiene la propagacion al padre
        e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation(); // detiene la propagacion al document
    };
}

class Padre extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            console.log('Click en el document, fuera de la tabla y fuera del padre');
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{height: '400px', backgroundColor: 'yellow', width: '400px'}} onClick={this._onClickHandler}>
                <Hijo />
            </div>
        );
    }

    _onClickHandler = (e) => {
        console.log('Click en el componente padre');
        e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation(); // detiene la propagacion al document
    }
}
```

Al hacer click en el componente 'Hijo', detienes la propagación del evento React (SyntheticEvent) llamando a la función stopPropagation, esto detiene la propagación del evento onClick de React y por ende el evento no se propaga al componente 'Padre' sin embargo solo detiene la propagación en el sistema de eventos de React, no en el evento nativo para eso se llama a la función e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation(). de este modo detienes la propagación al document.

Aquí una explicación mas detallada en ingles.

[Stop propagation only works with react events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415631/reactjs-syntheticevent-stoppropagation-only-works-with-react-events)

Answer (score 0):

En tiendo que lo que quieres es que cuando hagan `click` el elemento `<div class="tabla">Acá</div>`, se ejecute su *'otra' función*.

Intenta hacerlo así:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  // Si hiceron click sobre un elemento con clase 'tabla'
  if (evt.target.classList.contains('tabla')) {
    alert('mi func!')
  }
  else {
    alert("Click fuera de la tabla")
  }
  evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Socramg/ab2285ka/)

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es evitar manipular el DOM directamente

```
export default class Hijo extends Component {
    myFunc(){
      // whatever here
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="tabla" onClick={myFunc()}/>
        );
    }
}
```